# Regex in nginx location match extension without "resolve"

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I am not a god in Regular Expressions and stuck with a complex location regex.

I have a location block in my nginx config to make sure images and other media are cached. But if "resolve" is in the URL it should not match and skip the block. I can't get it to work. I have looked at a negative lookbegind but I think I do not completely understand how it works.

This is my block:

`location ~* \.(?:css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  //caching stuff
}`

It should match the following URL:

/media/cache/ps_product_admin_thumb/productimages/image.jpg

But ***not*** the following:

/media/cache/resolve/ps_product_admin_thumb/productimages/image.jpeg

Anyone who can send me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lookahead may help:

```
^(?!.*resolve).*\.(?:css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$
```

`(?!.*resolve)` makes sure no `resolve` exists in the string.

See [proof & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/P1pY4Y/1)